# onActivityResult not being called after FragmentActivity

Tags: android

I have an activity A that calls an activity B (FragmentActivity) using `startActivityForResult()`. Before activity B finishes by calling `finish()`, I use `setResult()`.  In spite of all of this, `onActivityResult()` is not called.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I'm not doing anything unconventional, or if this is an Android bug.

Seeing some of the suggestions on here, I've checked to see that I don't have `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` nor `android:noHistory="true"` set anywhere in my manifest file.

Calling activity B from A:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, MY_RESULT);
```

Finishing activity B:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
```

Overriding `onActivityResult()` in activity A:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**Edit 1**

I commented out nearly all of activity B's code (see below), leaving A's intact and the problem remained. So, A is definitely doing something strange that causes the problem.  Worse, I have done this with other activities (using the same code) without any problems!  A extends `ExpandableListActivity`, although I don't understand how any of that code would cause issues in `onActivityResult()`.  Logcat isn't giving me anything useful.

This is the code tested for activity B, for posterity's sake (though it seems to be that the problem is in A):

```
public class ActivityB extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_activityb);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("data", "Hello from ActivityB");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment/6147919#6147919

Comment: could you please put `ActivityB` code

Comment: what is `getActivity()` in this `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);`

Comment: instead put `this` for current activity or `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @AndrewFielden I just tried this now, but no luck thanks.  I'll post ActivityB's code in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to everyone that pointed me in the right direction.  I found the solution.  The issue was that I was doing `startActivityForResult()` in a `DialogFragment` so I should have done

```
    getActivity().startActivityForResult()
```

instead of just

```
    startActivityForResult()
```

then it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

try this and verify with your code:

ActivityA.java

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity{
   private static final int MY_RESULT = 0;
   private Button btnStart;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
        btnStart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
          startActivityForResult(intent, MY_RESULT);
        }
    });

  }

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), data.getStringExtra("data"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

ActivityB.java

```
public class ActivityB extends FragmentActivity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("data", "Hello from ActivityB");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Note : make sure you have added both the activity in your manifest file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried your code, commenting out pretty much everything else, and it behaves as it should, so it must be something I've done/not done that triggers my problem.  I'll post ActivityB's source in a little bit, thanks.